# Reading multiple pieces of data enclosed by a tag in XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I know that there are a couple questions regarding reading XML data into Java but none of the questions I've seen have the answer I need. (I also know little about XML terminology) I have a bunch of data that I need that appear to be enclosed in a tag. For example:

```
<powerplay ppg="28" ppopp="176" pppct=".159" pk="171" pkopp="193" pkpct=".886"/>
```

I'd like to be able to store the numbers as my information. Any information would be appreciated.

Note: the "powerplay" tag is enclosed by a

```
<team......../team>
```

tag, so is that simple to direct my program to this specific line through the DOM?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need ?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself yet? If yes, show some code and name the library you were using for parsing. Do you try to locate this specific line in the xml-file? If yes, what do does your program know about the line (ie, it is looking for the line with ppg="28" or just the first powerplay-tag inside a team-teag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

//given that the doc is your xml file
public NodeList getMainInfo(Document doc) {
    NodeList feed = doc.getElementsByTagName("powerplay");
    Node feedElement = feed.item(0);
    NodeList info = feedElement.getChildNodes();
    return info;
}

public String getPPG(NodeList info){
    Element powerplay = (Element) info;
    return info.getAttribute("ppg");
}

public String getPPOPP(NodeList info){
    Element powerplay = (Element) info;
    return info.getAttribute("ppopp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `org.w3c.dom` package? It is part of JAVA JDK so you wont need any additional libraries. I am using it by myself and must say it is not very complicated. Examples of usage you can find here [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) and API you will find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing the XML with Java SAX ([tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)), getting the attributes is doable by utilizing the attributes object in the [startElement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29) callback. [Attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html) are fairly easy to manipulate - if you know the name of the attribute you want, fetching it is a matter of simply calling [getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getValue%28java.lang.String%29).

This is a great solution for accessing XML data in Java and I would highly recommend it.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equals("powerplay")) {
        // Utilize attributes object to get your attributes.
    }
}
```

In the above example, we are having the handler check if the given element is a `powerplay` element and then handling its attributes accordingly.

One of the great things about the SAX parser is that it does not load the document you are parsing into memory. This is a very, very good thing if you have no control over the documents size or if the size of it is anticipated to be very large.